# Micronaut Declarative Http Client Requires @Body or you get a key in the JSON request

Tags: httpclient, micronaut

I kind of wanted to get some verification before I send a PR in for the documentation. I have the following operations interface:

```
public interface StatusOperations {

    @Get
    HttpResponse<List<StatusResponse>> findAll();

    @Post
    Single<StatusResponse> save(StatusRequest statusRequest);
}
```

And then the declarative client interface:

```
@Client("/api/statuses")
public interface StatusClient extends StatusOperations {

    @Override
    @Get
    HttpResponse<List<StatusResponse>> findAll();

    @Override
    @Post
    Single<StatusResponse> save(StatusRequest statusRequest);
}
```

And here is `StatusRequest`:

```
@Introspected
public class StatusRequest {

    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    private String message;

    // getter/setter stuff below
}
```

When I use the client to hit the API:

`StatusResponse response = client.save(new StatusRequest("Hello")).blockingGet();`

I am expecting this body to post:

`{"message": "Hello"}`

But what is actually posting is:

`{"statusRequest": { "message": "Hello"}}`

Which fails. However, if I modify the operations interface like so:

```
@Post
Single<StatusResponse> save(@Body StatusRequest statusRequest);
```

The post body is what I expect and everything work. The [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation) doesn't talk about this at all so I don't know if it is just missing or if I've discovered a bug or what. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I guess that the @Body is simply missing in the documentation. Would be great if you could raise a PR to clarify it.

Comment: So, I went back and read some more, and it's actually in the documentation. "For example, the following defines a URI template and the name parameter is used as part of the URI template, whilst @Body is used declare that the contents to send to the server are represented by the Pet POJO:" and then there is a example code for PetOperations. It's just not really clear. I'm going to see if i can clean it up and submit a PR.